# How to pass a Uri of a recorded video which is stored in mobile device to another activity

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-camera

I am trying to pass the Uri of a recorded video from my android mobile device to SecondActivity, but not able to get the uri.
Please suggest.

## MainActivity.java

```
viewModel.filePaths = new ArrayList<>();
viewModel.filePaths.add(uri);
customDialogBuilder.showLoadingDialog();
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("file_content", viewModel.filePaths);
startActivity(intent);
```

## MainViewModel.java

```
 public List<Uri> filePaths = new ArrayList<>();
```

## SecondActivity.java

```
viewModel.filePaths = (ArrayList<Uri>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("file_content");
```

## SecondViewModel.java

```
public List<Uri> filePaths;
```

Edit :
Actually the Url is for a Video file which I have recorded from camera and store to my device. I want to pass this recorded video path to SecondActivity, but it's showing blank screen on UI and null values in 2nd Activity

Comment: Are you getting any error ?

Comment: intent.putExtra("file_content", uri.toString()); Uri uri = Uri.parse( getIntent().getExtra("file_content");

Comment: https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/08/10/uri-access-lifetime-shorter-than-you-might-think.html

Comment: @MD please check my edit.

Comment: @blackapps thanks. But what about the ArrayList in models. How can I assign or change. Like ArrayList<Uri> ? I tried it but not working.

Comment: putParcebleArrayList()

Comment: @blackapps thanks for your valuable suggestion. If you want me to accept your answer then you can post it. :)